# Making a Module in Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, user-interface, module, accordion

i am new developing in drupal and using it. So, i am doing a new module to list a category table, and it products. So i need to make them to appear as a accordion style. So, i had these lines in my init hook:

```
function product_init()
{
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'Products') . '/js/products.js');
} 

function product_menu() {
    $items['list/products'] = array(
    'title' => 'List Products',
    'page callback' => 'products_list',
    'access callback' => TRUE
    );
    return $items;

}
```

But i am getting the list, without any style... I had added an alert in my js to test if is passing my js archive, but it never show when i put the URL in my browser( i mean myweb/list/products as i had defined in my menu hook).

So i had forgotten something, or i am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey, try adding a 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, and flushing your cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your `drupal_get_path()` statement...

From the name of your hooks (`product_menu()`, `product_init()`) your module is actually called `product`, not `Products`.

This should work:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'product') . '/js/products.js');
```